# MATLAB equivalent of the R function rank()?

Tags: r, matlab, rank

R have the following function, `rank()`

https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.4.1/topics/rank

What this function does is compute and return the order of each element in an ascending list.

(This is NOT the function `order()`, which returns the index each element would have in an ascending list.)

Does such a function exist in MATLAB? I suspect writing my own such function within MATLAB would be quite inefficient.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can use [`unique()`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/unique.html):

```
[~, ~, rank] = unique(A); % A is the array you want to rank
```

Be aware that MATLAB's `unique()` function will settle ties differently than R's `rank()` function.

---

Alternatively, if you want to settle ties like `rank()`, then you can use [`tiedrank()`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/tiedrank.html) instead, provided you have the Statistics Toolbox:

```
rank = tiedrank(A);
```

Comment: Does `tiedrank()` have the exact same default setting for resolving ties, etc.?

Comment: Yea, `rank()` and `tiedrank()` will both rank ties as averages by default. So the rank of `[10 20 30 40 20]` will come out to `[1.0 2.5 4.0 5.0 2.5]` using either function.